# arithmetic operation on time datatype sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column "Time" with Time as its Datatype.

I need to get 25% of the value in that column.

Please help. I've been banging my head on the wall for the solution.

Comment: the value in that column is 03:00:00. which means 3 hrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `TIME` to float value. According to [Data type conversion table](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC170617.gif) you can do it through `DATETIME`, so:

```
DECLARE @d time = '03:00:00';

SELECT CONVERT(float, CONVERT(datetime, @d)) * 0.25 -- this will be 25% of the value in float
```

And then do reverse conversion:

```
DECLARE @f float = 0.03125; -- this is result of previous select. 

SELECT CONVERT(time, CONVERT(datetime, @f)) --  Result = 00:45:00
```

So, in your query it will be:

```
SELECT ResultTime = CONVERT(time, CONVERT(datetime, (CONVERT(float, CONVERT(datetime, TimeColumn)) * 0.25)))
FROM Table
```

See [DEMO](http://rextester.com/VPHHFE23402)

Answer (score 0):

Convert from the date to Float

```
DECLARE @d time =getdate()
print @d
SELECT CONVERT(float , CONVERT(datetime, @d)) * 0.25
```

Comment: He has column with datatype `TIME`. So he can not convert time to float. And _conversion between `DATE` to `FLOAT`_ is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the best answer you can get, but i did it in one query :

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME, 
       CONVERT(DATETIME,
       CONVERT(FLOAT, 
       CONVERT(DATETIME, field )) / 4))
```

Here's a fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01b3f/7

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @time NUMERIC

set @TIME=(select cast(replace(replace(cast(cast(getdate() as time) as varchar),':',''),'.','') as NUMERIC)*.25)

IF LEN(@TIME)=12 BEGIN
SELECT '0'+SUBSTRING(CAST(@TIME AS VARCHAR(20)),0,2)+':'+SUBSTRING(CAST(@TIME AS VARCHAR(20)),3,2)+':'+SUBSTRING(CAST(@TIME AS VARCHAR(20)),5,2)+'.'+SUBSTRING(CAST(@TIME AS VARCHAR(20)),7,13)
END 
ELSE
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(@TIME AS VARCHAR(20)),0,2)+':'+SUBSTRING(CAST(@TIME AS VARCHAR(20)),3,2)+':'+SUBSTRING(CAST(@TIME AS VARCHAR(20)),5,2)+'.'+SUBSTRING(CAST(@TIME AS VARCHAR(20)),7,13)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
select convert(varchar, dateadd(s, datediff(s, '00:00:00' , t) * .25, '00:00:00'), 8)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/778b7/10)